# Visualize Apache Log files

Tags: apache, logging

I want to quickly and efficiently analyze my apache log files. 
Is there a software that would read in apache log files and display visually (no parser) with a menu statistics such as distinct IPs, requests type, ...?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have (odd) requirement to not have a parser, you'll need to output your logs in a descriptive way (e.g. json).  So, update your apache config to write json, then use a shipper like filebeat to send them to a store like elasticsearch where you can visualize them with a tool like kibana.

The parser (logstash, in ELK's case) will allow you to add more value to your log data, so I wouldn't dismiss it so quickly.

Comment: Parsers would of course be preprocessing of the viewer. However, I am more interested in the results than in learning how to use a parser. Can you please send me a link to the parser of your choice?

Comment: In the ELK stack (from elastic.co), the parser is logstash.  It takes in logs and writes fields to elasticsearch.  https://www.elastic.co/

Comment: But I also like the JSON option. Thanks for your input!